# how to extrude neighboring vertices without creating a face in between?

Tags: vertices, extrude

As in question. Check the picture. I do not want any faces inbetween.
Kind regards.[image]

Please see the picture:
1) - original
2) - after extruding using E (+Z)
3) - after 2) and deleting the faces (not what i want)
4) - after using Edge -> Extrude edges (as in answer below) -> That is what I want, sorted. Thanks[image]

Comment: You can always delete faces and keep vertices or edges ... post facto.

Comment: Control Click can add vertices without faces.

Comment: It's hard to figure out what's your goal from one picture. Could you upload another to show what you want to achieve?

Comment: You may also want to show your question in edit mode with a highlight.  This would improve readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to get to vertices menu, then **extrude vertices** will extrude only the vertices.

[image]

Comment: You may also context click for the same menu.  That might be considered very 2.8 style for edit mode.

Comment: worked, thanks, I have also precised the question.